# $_POST is empty and it seems to be different then the 100s of posts I have found about this

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I have a table that is part of a form. You are supposed to select one of the rows of the table using checkboxs that are in the last table column and then submit them with the submit button at the bottom. The names of the info from your selected column are then supposed to be sent to another file via  method="post" . The problem is that $_POST is always empty. I have scoured this site and others for an answer and while I have found lots of posts about empty $_POST none of them have been able to help me. I will share a simplified version of the code I think could be relevant and bellow that I will list some of the things I have tried that have not worked.

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="f1"></form>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    <?php foreach ($positions as $position): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $position["symbol"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $position["______"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $position["______"] ?></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?= $position['symbol'] ?>" form="f1"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" form="f1">
```

A few notes on the above code.

Note 1:  The information in positions is from a MySQL table and another web site(the info from the other web site is unformatted text).

Note 2:  PHP code is used to create the rows of the table and fill the value in the checkbox because how many rows and what information they will contain will vary with the account.

Note 3:  The information should be sent to the same controller document that provided the content for this page. I used an  if  else  statement vary its actions when it receives info from the attribute  post.

Here is the relevant code from the controller that the information is being sent too.

```
    <?php

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {
            if (empty($_POST))
            {
                apologize("No selection made");
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }

    ?>
```

At first I thought that the problem was using the php code to fill the  input  elements  value  so I tried a number of variations of the php code. However none of them worked and I found no mention anywhere that I looked of this code being bad. Also note that if I view the source page source for the  table  and  input  they show the correct value being inserted into the  input  value  in the html that is generated for the page.

Now being fairly confident that the PHP was not the problem I began reaserching reasons that  $_POST might be empty even though a value was passed to it from  submit. Here are some of the reasons I found.

1. The url in form does not match the destination but travels through some variation of a redirect during which the  $_POST  is emptied.
2. The information in  $_POST  is affected by  Jquery  somehow and is therefore formatted wrong. I don't know anything about  Jquery  so this one was kind of confusing to read through and apparently happens quit often.
3. There is a maximum amount of data that  $_POST  is allowed to transfer and someone has gone over it.
4. Someone typed  $_post  instead of  $_POST.
5. Someone has done a custom configuration of  apache  or something else and it is somehow causing the problem.
6. The information is actually coming through but is not being recognized because of formatting.

There are a number of others that I have found thus far none of them seem to apply to my case. If you have any questions or want any more information about my code or what I have tried thus far let me know.

If anyone has a solution, thought, or even an inkling about what is going on and how to fix it let me know all help will be greatly appreciated.

(edit)

This is the HTML that my code generates.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

        <head>

            <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

                        <title>C$50 Finance: Sell</title>

            <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="container">

                <div id="top">
                    <a href="/"><img alt="C$50 Finance" src="/img/logo.gif"/></a>
                </div>

                <div id="middle">
    <p id="p1"><b>CASH: $ </b>10,000.00</p>

    <form action="sell.php" method="post" id="f1"></form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>symbol</th>
            <th>shares</th>
            <th>price*</th>
            <th>sell</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AAPL</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>106.98</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="AAPL" form="f1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AMZN</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>299.07</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="AMZN" form="f1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Sell" form="f1">
    <div>
        <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
    </div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>

                <footer>
                    Copyright &#169; John Harvard
                </footer>

            </div>

        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You need to debug this further.  The problem is either server side or client-side... it's unlikely both.  Show the HTML generated by your PHP app.  Does it look right to you?  Next, check the network tab when you do your POST.  Is the data there?  It probably isn't, and then you know that the problem is happening before the form is submitted.  If the data is being sent to the server. do a `print_r($_POST)` right off the bat in your code to see where it's getting blown away later.  Do some basic debugging, and you can knock out almost all the possible causes in 1 minute.

Comment: I have looked at the HTML generated by my PHP app before and it looks right. I have also used print_r($_POST) before and all I get is empty brackets. I have just now at your suggestion looked over the network tab and as far as I can tell the you are right the data is not there but I am not certain that I am reading the network tab right.

Comment: Alright, if both of those things are true, then all of your PHP code is irrelevant to your question.  Post a reproducible example of the HTML that is causing no data to be posted.  This will likely come down to a validation error causing your `<form>` tag to be closed early or something similar.

Comment: I have added to my post the HTML that is generated by my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to replace value in the checkbox input with name. I am not entirely  sure why this works but it does.